# Twilio - How to determine which end hung up first?

Tags: twilio

When examining incoming calls in Twilio, I would like to determine which person hung up first. Was it the caller or the callee?

This is a basic use case for when a person calls in and the connection is forwarded to another phone line (as opposed to a browser).

Currently I'm looking at the arguments in the status call back, but I don't see anything that indicates which party actually ended the call.

Answer (score 4):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There's no specific information about which party ended the call. You could examine the timestamp of the `completed` event from the `statusCallback` to see which one of the legs occurred first.

Alternatively, if the calls are connected via a `<Dial>` then you could add a [URL as an `action` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#action) to the `<Dial>`. If the dialled party hangs up then the `action` URL will be requested with a [`DialCallStatus` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#dialcallstatus) of 'completed'. If the caller hangs up, the action won't be called. You could infer the side that hung up from this information.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Answer (score 1):

Add an action listener for Twilio Action afterHangupCall.  If Agent hung up, this action will be executed.  Otherwise, customer hung up.